# Supabase bucket - new row violates row-level security policy for table "objects"

Tags: supabase

I am having an issue with uploading avatars to my supabase bucket as its giving me "new row violates row-level security policy for table "objects"". I tried other StackOverflow solutions and nothing.
Before trying to upload I log in using supabse so my user is authenticated yet its still not letting me upload. I added this policy in storage.objects:

`(role() = 'authenticated'::text)` and clicked the insert button. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I assume its something to do with the policies. Thanks

This is how I'm trying to upload my avatar:

```
try {
  const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
    .from("/public/avatars")
    .upload(`${values.email}.png`, values.avatar, {
      cacheControl: "3600",
      upsert: true,
    });
  if (error) throw error;
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

add new policy and enjoy :)

Because **upsert** need DELETE and UPDATE

[image]

Comment: This is terribly permissive, basically allowing auth'd users to do anything they want to the bucket to any folders.

Comment: @BradyDowling I agree that this dumbed-down example is, but in the SQL expression you can do far more, such as verifying the user authenticated's role, etc. Supabase is pretty powerful like that.

Comment: The image does not show...

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have a bucket named `public` with a folder named `avatars`, correct?

In that case you would upload as follows:

```js
const avatarFile = event.target.files[0]
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .storage
  .from('public')
  .upload(`avatars/avatar1.png`, avatarFile, {
    cacheControl: '3600',
    upsert: false
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem! In Next.js the solution is to use "supabase" instance of auth-helpers ex: const supabase = createServerActionComponentClient({cookies}); instead of the normal supabase client created from key & url.